# To import MS Band packages, what else do I have to do other than typing 'import' statement in .java?

Tags: java, android, package

I want to make my app connect to MS Band, get some data from it, and save the data in form of SQLite. Using the sample file given, I gathered the data I want; but I need to implement this in the actual app.

Referencing https://developer.microsoftband.com/content/docs/microsoft%20band%20sdk.pdf, I put the following statements in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.microsoft.band.service.access.BIND_BAND_SERVICE"/>
```

And I put these in `.java` file.

```
import com.microsoft.band.BandClient;
import com.microsoft.band.BandClientManager;
import com.microsoft.band.BandException;
import com.microsoft.band.BandInfo;
import com.microsoft.band.BandIOException;
import com.microsoft.band.ConnectionState;
import com.microsoft.band.UserConsent;

import com.microsoft.band.sensors.BandHeartRateEvent;
import com.microsoft.band.sensors.BandHeartRateEventListener;
import com.microsoft.band.sensors.BandRRIntervalEvent;
import com.microsoft.band.sensors.BandRRIntervalEventListener;
import com.microsoft.band.sensors.HeartRateConsentListener;
```

Then I got an error saying that symbol `microsoft` cannot be resolved. But these two tasks are all I got from the documentation. What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Microsoft Band is being discontinued, and the [official developer site of the SDK](https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK) shows "The Microsoft Band SDK is no longer available" in the download list.

if, despite this, you still want to use it, you can [download the SDK for Android through Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160802072410/https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/download/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK%20and%20Samples%20for%20Android.zip).

To import the library, just copy the **microsoft-band-1.3.20307.2.jar** file to the **libs** folder, and you should be able to use it in your project.

Comment: What does that 'be able to use it in project'? I downloaded that `.jar` file from your link and but in the correct folder; is it all done? Or do you mean I have to do something more?

Comment: plus the `import` statements still show that symbols cannot be resolved.